# Hide a page from the navigation menu on blog hosted on Wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress.com, wordpress.com-themes

I have a blog hosted on Wordpress.com.

My navigation menu includes a link to each page I've added to the blog. I would like to add a few additional pages to the blog, but not have them appear in the navigation menu.

Is there a way to hide a page from the navigation in a theme when running on the Wordpress.com hosting environment?

Note: Using the [Custom Design upgrade](http://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/) to apply a CSS fix might be a solution, but I am looking for a solution which does not require any upgrades.

Comment: See the [support page](http://en.support.wordpress.com/menus/) regarding custom menus.

Comment: @Alex - Thank you, sorry I missed that. Do you want to move your comment to the "Answer" section so I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a rather lengthy explanation on the wordpress.com [support page regarding custom menus](http://en.support.wordpress.com/menus/), so I will just post the link to it: http://en.support.wordpress.com/menus/

You should find the required info there.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. And I think that the info is not really specific to the Twenty Eleven theme, right? I might edit the question to make it more general so it applies to any theme hosted on Wordpress.com. Let me know if you know of any reason why that would not make sense.

Comment: @ShannonWagner it does; that man page is general, so I think it’s OK.